# What would cause a "Collection is read-only" exception during a query with DBContext in EFCore?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-3.1

I get the following exception when performing a basic query with my DBContext and I can't figure it out.
It is a Console Application.

The exception being thrown is:

```
        fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
          An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'JobAssist.Services.ArticleBankMgmt.Infrastructure.ArticleBankContext'.
          System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.
             at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>.Add(T value)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrICollectionAccessor`3.Add(Object entity, Object value, Boolean forMaterialization)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.AddToCollection(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean forMaterialization)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalMixedEntityEntry.AddToCollection(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean forMaterialization)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.AddToCollection(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean fromQuery)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.SetReferenceOrAddToCollection(InternalEntityEntry entry, INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean fromQuery)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.ToDependentFixup(InternalEntityEntry dependentEntry, InternalEntityEntry principalEntry, IForeignKey foreignKey, Boolean fromQuery)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.InitialFixup(InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean fromQuery)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NavigationFixer.TrackedFromQuery(InternalEntityEntry entry)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.TrackedFromQuery(InternalEntityEntry entry)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.MarkUnchangedFromQuery()
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTrackingFromQuery(IEntityType baseEntityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext.StartTracking(IEntityType entityType, Object entity, ValueBuffer valueBuffer)
             at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , ResultCoordinator )
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.CustomShaperCompilingExpressionVisitor.<PopulateIncludeCollection>g__ProcessCurrentElementRow|9_0[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity](<>c__DisplayClass9_0`2& )
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.CustomShaperCompilingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeCollection[TIncludingEntity,TIncludedEntity](Int32 collectionId, QueryContext queryContext, DbDataReader dbDataReader, ResultCoordinator resultCoordinator, Func`3 parentIdentifier, Func`3 outerIdentifier, Func`3 selfIdentifier, Func`5 innerShaper, INavigation inverseNavigation, Action`2 fixup, Boolean trackingQuery)
             at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
             at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
System.NotSupportedException: Collection is read-only.
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>.Add(T value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrICollectionAccessor`3.Add(Object entity, Object value, Boolean forMaterialization)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.AddToCollection(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean forMaterialization)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalMixedEntityEntry.AddToCollection(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry value, Boolean forMaterialization)
   at Microsoft.EntityFramew
```

The code is:

```
    var bank = articleBankContext.ArticleBanks.FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(bank.Id);
```

In my DBContext, the OnModelCreating code is:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder));
        }

        // Build the model
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ClientRequestEntityTypeConfiguration());

        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleBank>(ab =>
        {
            ab.OwnsMany(ab => ab.ArticleTags, at =>
            {
                at.WithOwner();
                at.Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
                at.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");
                at.ToTable("ArticleBankTags");
            });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleBank>(ab =>
        {
            ab.OwnsMany(ab => ab.Sources, s =>
            {
                s.WithOwner();
                s.Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
                s.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");
                s.ToTable("ArticleBankSources");
            });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().OwnsOne(a => a.JSeeker).OwnsOne(a => a.Name);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().OwnsMany(a => a.Ratings, ar => ar.ToTable("ArticleRatings").OwnsOne(ar => ar.JSeeker).OwnsOne(js => js.Name));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().OwnsOne(a => a.Source).WithOwner();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().OwnsMany(a => a.Tags).WithOwner();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleBank>().HasMany(s => s.Articles);

        ////Create Shadow Properties
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleBank>().Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleBank>().Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().ToTable("ArticleBankArticles");
    }
```

How would I know what "read only collection" are they talking about?  I havent had an issue like this in other projects in the solution.  I have a "PrePopulateDB()" that actually uses the same context and adds the appropriate data to the database.

Here are the declarations in ArticleBanK:

I create the lists in the constructor.

```
private readonly List<ArticleTag> _articleTags; 
public IEnumerable<ArticleTag> ArticleTags => _articleTags.AsReadOnly(); /
private readonly List<Article> _articles; 
public IEnumerable<Article> Articles => _articles.AsReadOnly();
```

Also what is wierd, in the DBContext.Model.DebugView there is no field for the Sources property:

```
  EntityType: ArticleBank
    Navigations:
      Articles (_articles, IEnumerable<Article>) Collection ToDependent Article
      ArticleTags (_articleTags, IEnumerable<ArticleTag>) Collection ToDependent ArticleBank.ArticleTags#ArticleTag
        Annotations:
          EagerLoaded: True
      Sources (no field, IEnumerable<ArticleSource>) Collection ToDependent ArticleBank.Sources#ArticleSource
        Annotations:
          EagerLoaded: True
```

Comment: How are `ArticleTags` and `Sources` defined in `ArticleBank`, hopefully not as a read only collections.

Comment: I removed the "readonly" and still the same error.

Comment: Added code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error too.
my entities had many to many relationships and when I wanted to create a record I was getting a collection is read-only error.
When I checked my class later, there was a private constructor and an internal constructor. It was fixed when I updated the internal constructor to public and migrated again.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem.

I wasnt following the By Convention.  My navigation field (Sources) and the property of (_articleSources) didnt align.

Comment: You're a life saver. That's the least descriptive error I've encountered